# Key Value Pairs from SQL Server DB to Javascript via C#

Tags: .net, sql-server, list, c#-4.0

The title pretty much says it all.

I need to send a set of int/string pairs from my DB via a web service to javascript.

As I see it, I can use either `HashTable, Dictionary<int, string>, List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> or a CustomObject[] or List<CustomObject>`.

Which one is better/faster?

I do not use any custom conversion, I just want to return the "correct" type/list from the web service.

I know there are tons of questions/answers about the other direction (JS to DB)...

Comment: The entire list is only 41 rows and the longest string is only 20 chars, so memory is not a major issue

Answer (score 0):

None of those look right, because they all want to load the entire collection of pairs into memory at once. That will be bad for performance of a web site, that could need to take requests more many of these at the same time... memory can balloon beyond what you expect very quickly.

Try for either an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,string>>` or a direct JSON response, and in both cases you want to write each pair directly from your data reader to the response stream.

Comment: Maybe I should add that the entire list is only 41 rows

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have control over both sides of the equation, you may want to take a look at WCF Data Services (OData). Doing so will eliminate 90% of the coding you will end up doing for reads from the database, and OData provides a JavaScript library to simplify that side as well. It has paid dividends for me.